# How to copy rich text with hash links (inline) without copying the page url?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, clipboard.js

I am trying to copy some text from a page without copying the entire page url for the inline (#links).

Here's my example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adxhoz5v/10/

When you press the copy button, it copies the entire link and the clipboard, when pasted into another rich text editor, looks like this:

```
<p>But it is a fascinating CSS trick and the web is a big place with an unknowable magnitude of situations where sometimes weird solutions are needed.</p>
<h3><a id="technique-1-directional-trickery" class="aal_anchor" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true#technique-1-directional-trickery" aria-hidden="true"></a>Technique #1: Directional Trickery</h3>
<p>The trick here is to have the scrolling parent element use&nbsp;<code>direction: rtl</code>&nbsp;(or the opposite of whatever your primary direction is), and have the inside of the scrolling element switch back to whatever your normal is.</p>
```

Notice how it copies the inline link with url of the jsfiddle page (page url):

> **href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true#technique-1-directional-trickery"**

My question is, is there a way to prevent this default behaviour so that I am only left with the inline links in my clipboard. Like so:

> **href="#technique-1-directional-trickery"**

To reproduce, please use your desktop or any online rich text editor like: https://html-online.com/editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it will always add the **baseURI** of the document for rich text output. Since this property is automatically populated and read-only there's no way to avoid this.

Luckily there's a workaround though. You can utilize the [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) interface to obtain the data of your DIVs `.outerHTML` property instead of relying on the ClipboardJS library. Rich text is preserved by setting the format of the copied text to `text/html`.

Here's an example based on your fiddle:

```js
function copyToClipboard(val) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", val);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
}
```

```html
<div id="target">

  <p>But it is a fascinating CSS trick and the web is a big place with an unknowable magnitude of situations where sometimes weird solutions are needed.</p>
  <h3>
    <a id="technique-1-directional-trickery" class="aal_anchor" href="#technique-1-directional-trickery" aria-hidden="true"></a>Technique #1: Directional Trickery</h3>
  <p>The trick here is to have the scrolling parent element use&nbsp;<code>direction: rtl</code>&nbsp;(or the opposite of whatever your primary direction is), and have the inside of the scrolling element switch back to whatever your normal is.</p>
</div>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('target').outerHTML)">
   Copy to clipboard <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20px" width="20px">
  <path d="M128 768h256v64H128v-64z m320-384H128v64h320v-64z m128 192V448L384 640l192 192V704h320V576H576z m-288-64H128v64h160v-64zM128 704h160v-64H128v64z m576 64h64v128c-1 18-7 33-19 45s-27 18-45 19H64c-35 0-64-29-64-64V192c0-35 29-64 64-64h192C256 57 313 0 384 0s128 57 128 128h192c35 0 64 29 64 64v320h-64V320H64v576h640V768zM128 256h512c0-35-29-64-64-64h-64c-35 0-64-29-64-64s-29-64-64-64-64 29-64 64-29 64-64 64h-64c-35 0-64 29-64 64z"/>
</svg>
</button>
```